# jQuery Selectable - change class to selected based on Array data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a c# variable created from a SQL Select query which is passed to a javascript array:

```
var positionTagsJS = @Html.Raw(positionTags);
```

I want to use these values in the JS array to change the class of my selectable to 'ui-selected'. The selectables are created with this:

```
var db = Database.Open("mydb");
       foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT positiontagName FROM positiontag"))
      {
         var positiontagName = item.positiontagName;
        <ul class="selectable" id="selectable1">
             <li class="ui-state-default" id="@positiontagName">
                 @positiontagName
             </li>
        </ul>
      }
```

So I have a group of selectables with list item ids based on my tags. Some subset of these are in my positionTagsJS array. I want to change the class of those ones to .ui-selected. I've tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be able to find the ids or maybe it finds the ids but doesn't trigger a class change for some reason. Here is the code.

```
  function loadSet() 
     {
           $('#selectable1 .ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');

//all this is doing up to here is clearing any selections which works
//this next bit doesn't work...

           for (var i = 0, len = positionTagsJS.length; i < len; i++) {
           $('#selectable1')
          .find("li:contains('" + positionTagsJS[i] + "')")
          .addClass('ui-selected');
      }
```

If I select tag1 it changes the class of the first item in the list but nothing more. Here is what my 'view page source' looks like to give you sense of the ul li bits I'm trying to grab onto.

```
 <ul class="selectable" id="selectable1">
     <li class="ui-state-default" id="tag1">
           tag1
     </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="selectable" id="selectable1">
     <li class="ui-state-default" id="tag2">
           tag2
     </li>
  </ul>
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

I thought maybe I needed to think of ul as parent and li as child. and try to home in on my selector with one of those methods but am at an impasse.

Comment: When you are doing this loop: `foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT positiontagName FROM positiontag"))`, why not look to see if the item exists in your array at that point, and add the class when creating the selectable?

Comment: Okay, hadn't thought of that. Would I just use c# .net to see if the @positiontagName is in my original c# Array 'positionTags'. I would need to switch to jQuery to trigger the class change then right?

Comment: Something like this...
 
    `<ul class="selectable" id="selectable1">
         if (positionTags.Contains(@positiontagName))
              {<script>$('#selectable1 .selectable > #@positiontagName').addClass('ui-selected') </script>
   }`

right after `var positiontagName = item.positiontagName;` which doesn't work as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why this works but I have combined devlin's suggested c# approach with my original jQuery code and it works. First, in the foreach loop as devlin suggested an IF statement.

```
var db = Database.Open("mydb");
       foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT positiontagName FROM positiontag"))
      {
         var positiontagName = item.positiontagName;
         var myClass = "";
         if (positionTags.Contains(@positiontagName))
                        {
                            myClass = myClass + " ui-selected";
                        }
        <ul class="selectable" id="selectable1">
             <li class="ui-state-default @myClass" id="@positiontagName">
                 @positiontagName
             </li>
        </ul>
      }
```

While it seems this alone should change the classes of the list items it does not. I also needed to run a variation of my original script after the foreach.

```
      <script>loadSet();</script>
```

which calls

```
    var positionTagsJS = @Html.Raw(positionTags);
    function loadSet() {           
        for (var i = 0, len = positionTagsJS.length; i < len; i++) {
            $('#selectable1')
          .find("li:contains('" + positionTagsJS[i] + "')")
            .addClass('ui-selected');
        }
    }
```

These seem completely redundant to me since they are both (C# code and JQuery code) just changing the class of the list item to "ui-selected". However neither will work independently but with both parts in I get the necessary behavior. There must be a better way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve your desired result by checking for whether or not the item exists in your array at the point where you're building the selectable:

```
foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT positiontagName FROM positiontag"))
  {
     var positiontagName = item.positiontagName;
     var myClass = "selectable";
     if (positionTags.Contains(positiontagName)) {
        myClass = myClass + " ui-selected"
     }
    <ul class="@myClass" id="selectable1">
         <li class="ui-state-default" id="@positiontagName">
             @positiontagName
         </li>
    </ul>
  }
```

Comment: should be `myClass = myClass + " ui-selected"` right?

It is generating the right code when I click view source I see

    `<ul class="selectable ui-selected" id="selectable1">`
    `<li class="ui-state-default" id="Chief Technology Officer">`
    `Chief Technology Officer`
    `</li>`
    `</ul>`

But it doesn't toggle those on. My script is up above. Maybe I need to re-call something to get the selectables to show.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the class being `ui-selected` without the dot.  If the source looks correct, I would use `console.log()` at various points in your script (assuming the toggle is in JS ... I'm not entirely clear what toggle you're referring to).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work by just using the c# approach to change the class to ui-selected but when I combined this approach with my original jQuery approach it works. I'm going to post the complete answer so I can show the code used.